# Angular2.1 Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: http, angular

So, I'm currently trying to send a HTTP request, I'm doing everything exactly like in [official guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) and it's wont work (as usual when you make deal with Angular2)

Here is my app.module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes }   from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { PageComponent } from './modules/Affiliate/affiliate.component';
import { NotFoundComponent }   from './not-found.component';


const routes: Routes =
    [
        { path: 'page', component: PageComponent },
        { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }
    ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

And here is my service, where I'm trying to send a http request

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class GridService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getTableRaws(url): Promise<any> {
            return this.http.get(url)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => response.json().data as any)
                .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Any ideas, please

Comment: Where are you using `getTableRaws`?

Comment: It should have work, only `GridService` missing in `providers` of `AppModule`

Comment: Added `GridService` to `providers` - no result

Comment: getTableRaws is used in my component this.gridService.getTableRaws(this.url).then(dataset => this.dataset = dataset);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that works for me:

```
constructor(@Inject(Http) private http: Http) {}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in angularjs but I highly doubt that's the way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Following the docs, I guess you missed the data type for the `url` param:

```
getTableRaws(url: string): Promise<any> {
...
}
```

#### UPDATE:

You need to add `GridService` as a provider in `app.module`. Refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40192108/888278).

If you have made these changes then update your code in the question and also provide the contents of app.component here.

Comment: Definately, data typing is awesome feature of typescript, but it is not required. That function works perfect with test data instead of `http` service injection

Comment: Registering `GridService` as a provider doesn't work, I think that is not necessary anymore, but I can't find any information in Angular 2.1 change log. Anyway - thank for help!

Comment: I'm using angular 2.1.2 and using the http module the same way you did in your code and it works for me perfectly. Maybe something else is messing up with the import. Kindly update your answer should you figure out the reason.